# Drop factor from formula when less than two levels

Tags: r

I want to be able to drop a term from a formula based on whether or not a factor has less than 2 levels.

My setup is that I want to run a large number of the same logit models for different subsets of data.  The problem is that, for some subsets, not some factors may take only 1 value.

Here is an example:

```
depvar <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=T)
bin1 <- rep(1, 100)
cont1 <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(depvar=depvar, bin1=bin1, cont1=cont1)
formla <- as.formula("depvar ~ bin1 + cont1")
logit.reg <- glm(formla, data=df, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

I would like to be able to somehow drop `bin1` from the formula automatically
when it only takes one value.

Comment: Put something like this `as.formula(paste0("depvar ~",if(length(levels(bin1)))"bin1+" else "","cont1"))`. Note that here `bin1` is a continuous variable and hence has no levels, but you can change that via `bin1=as.factor(bin1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like a simple if/else should suffice:

```
if(length(unique(df$bin)) > 1) {
  formla <- as.formula("depvar ~ bin1 + cont1")
} else {
  formla <- as.formula("depvar ~ cont1")
}
```

Note that *bin1* is not a factor in your example (can use `as.factor()` to coerce it to one though)

Comment: heh basically the same thing but in 5 lines